# Can the compiler avoid reloading the target?

Tags: origen-sdk

The [Origen compiler](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/compiler/introduction/) defaults to reloading the target when [running in inline mode](https://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/compiler/inline/).  This slows down the compiler performance, can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

The inline compiler call can be passed the 'preserve_target' option to avoid reloading the target.

```
Origen.compile("#{Origen.root}/templates/my_template.txt.erb", preserve_target: true)
```